# Try-Catch, return to the start of the loop (java)

Tags: java, loops, exception, try-catch, do-while

I want to get back to the start of the loop if the catch happened, so the user can input the date in the right format.

```
System.out.print("Enter date (Format DD.MM.JJJJ)");
    String date = eingabe.next();
    SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
    Date dateStandardFormat = null;
    do {
     try {
         dateStandardFormat = dateStandardFormat.parse(datum);  
    
     } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {                            
        System.out.println("date invalid! Please enter the date in Format DD.MM.YYYY");
        validity = true;
     } 
     }while(!validity);
```

But if I get the throw, it brings me back in a perma loop. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: you should read the date after. you start the loop

Comment: just move `validity = true` from `catch` block to `try` block.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
        boolean validity = false;
        Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);

        Date parsedDate = null;
        SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");

        System.out.println("Enter date (Format DD.MM.JJJJ)");

        do {

            String date = eingabe.next();

            try {
                parsedDate = dateStandardFormat.parse(date);
                validity = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Date invalid! Please enter the date in Format DD.MM.YYYY");
            }
        } while(!validity);

        System.out.println("Parsed date: " + parsedDate.toString());
```

My output from this code:

```
Enter date (Format DD.MM.JJJJ)
  Hello!
Date invalid! Please enter the date in Format DD.MM.YYYY
  27.10.2019
Parsed date: Sun Jan 27 00:10:00 CET 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can not have two objects declared with the same local variable name in the same method, for example:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
 Date dateStandardFormat = null;
```

This is a 'no go' and won't even allow for compiling. Below would be good enough if you plan on using these troublesome classes:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
Date newDate = null;
```

If you look closely to the string date pattern used for `SimpleDateFormat` you will notice the `mm` within the pattern. This designation is for **minutes** not for **months**. You need to change this to `MM` (uppercase **M**) so that the formatter knows you mean **months** otherwise you will just end up getting some obscure date that in no way relates to the date supplied by the User. The String pattern for the **SimpleDateFormat** constructor should be: `dd.MM.yyyy`, for example:.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

And where does `datum` come from? `dateStandardFormat = dateStandardFormat.parse(datum);`. This should be: `newDate = dateStandardFormat.parse(date);`.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateStandardFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date newDate = null;
    
boolean validity = false;
while (!validity) {
    System.out.print("Enter date (Format: DD.MM.YYYY): -> ");
    String strDate = eingabe.next();
    try {
        newDate = dateStandardFormat.parse(strDate);
        validity = true;
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Date invalid! (" + strDate + ") Please try again...");
    }
}
System.out.println(newDate);
```

---

**On A Side:**

If you can, you try and avoid using the antique **Date** and **SimpleDateFormat** classes since they are well known for being troublesome. Instead use the **LocalDate**, **LocalDateTime**, and other classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package and the [DateFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DateFormatter.html) / [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes (java 8+). Here is an example:

```
Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
LocalDate date = null;
String strDate = "";
boolean validity = false;
while (!validity) {
    System.out.print("Enter date (format: DD.MM.YYYY): -> ");
    strDate = eingabe.nextLine().trim();
    if (strDate.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        strDate = "N/A";
        break;
    }
    else if (strDate.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You must enter a date or enter 'n' for "
                         + "\"N/A\"!" +  System.lineSeparator() 
                         + "Try again..." + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    else {
        try {
            date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);
            strDate = date.format(formatter);
            /* The supplied date will be considered Invalid if it is
               found to be before the Current Date.   */
            if (date.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
                System.out.println("Date invalid! (" + strDate
                    + ") That date has already expired!" + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Please try again..." + System.lineSeparator());
                continue;
            }
            validity = true;
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Date invalid! (" + strDate
                    + ") Please try again..." + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("User Supplied:  " + strDate);
```

You may also notice that, knowing 2022 it is not a Leap Year but the User was to enter `31.02.2022`, the day value will be automatically corrected to the proper end of month: `28.02.2022`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right with the troublesome and I changed it to your recommendation.

Comment: I have another question. Can I not allow the user to put a date which already expired?

Comment: @PizzaE4ter Use an `if` statement and a condition that includes something like `date.isAfter(expirationLocalDate)`.

Comment: isAfter cant be found

Comment: Could you also explain what LocalDate.parse(strdate, formatter) and strDate = date.format(formatter) does please?

Comment: @PizzaE4ter - See the addition to the new `LocalDate` code block  in the answer above. Now, dates supplied which are before the current date will be considered invalid. It is highly recommended that you read the documentation contained within the links I provided in answer. Time for you to do a little research

Comment: `LocalDate.parse(strdate, formatter)` - You need this to convert the string supplied by User to a **LocalDate** object. The `date.format(formatter)` is required because **LocalDate** has only one format which is `yyyy-MM-dd` you need the `date.format(formatter)` to convert that to a string in the desired format of `dd.MM.yyyy`. You want this conversion to take place rather than just using the User supplied input because of the automatic corrections made as explained in the answer for improper month end days like `31.02.2022`. There is no such thing as 31 days in a February. (couldn't resist).

Comment: Thank you very much. That really explained me a lot. But still I dont know how I can set the expired date. the isAfter doesnt work because I dont use the Date format.

Comment: I've already added that feature in my last edit within the second code block which uses **LocalDate**. Any date before the Current Date is considered invalid. If you want a different date other than the Current Date then...change it (`LocalDate.now()`) to whatever date you want. The example code already shows you how to create a **LocalDate** object from a String date. You will only learn by trying to code....not by letting everyone else code for you. There is more to coding than just eating Pizza.